# Is there a way to connect 1 row unique key and display its data in a form?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am beginner on PHP and mySQL. Right now I am creating simple database to record and track purchase orders. I want to create HTML table that can display data from mySQL (already done), and on the [ID] column, I want it to be hyperlink and redirected to another php (form.php), and display all data in the row. Please help how to achieve that? Thank you for your expert advise.

```
`
<thead>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>UMR</th>
<th>DATE</th>
<th>PART NUMBER</th>
<th class="text-right">DESC</th>
<th class="text-right">PURCHASE ORDER</th>
<th class="text-right">AWB</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php while ($dataUmr = mysqli_fetch_array($umr)) {
echo "<tr>
<td>".$dataUmr['orderId']."</td>
<td>".$dataUmr['umr']."</td>
<td>".$dataUmr['date']."</td>
<td>".$dataUmr['partNumber']."</td>
<td>".$dataUmr['description']."</td>
<td>".$dataUmr['poDetail']."</td>
<td>".$dataUmr['awb']."</td>
</tr>";
`
```

[Table and form example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kykyj.png)

Comment: When you add your link into the table, add the ID as part of the query string,  for example `yoursite.com/form.php?ID=3` or `"yoursite.com/form.php?ID={$id}"` then on the `form.php` check for the id using get `$id = isset($_GET['ID']) ? $_GET['ID'] : false;` and then do your query etc. for that row.  Be aware that you cannot trust data from `$_GET` or `$_POST` and should use things like prepared statements etc.

Comment: One last thing, I feel compelled to tell you that when you use the double quote `"` there is no need to do it this way `"string".$dataUmr['orderId']."string"` instead you can just do `"string{$dataUmr['orderId']}string"` which saves you 2 keystrokes. The `{}` are optional in most cases (except like method calls), but I think it looks better in my IDE editor so.  It may not seem like much but it adds up.  This is known as "variable interpolation" which is a fancy way of saying PHP will treat that as a variable even if it's in a string.  Note that this does not apply to the single quote `'`

Answer (score 1):

First of All, You should know about GET Request. BY means of GET request you can send data to another page using URL.
Example: sitename.com?id=10

In your case you should use like this ->>
             `

```
    <td><a href='form.php?id=".$dataUmr['orderId']."' >".$dataUmr['orderId']."</a></td>
```

This will go to form.php?id={your_data}

NOW On the **FORM.PHP**

you may use ID variable like this    $_GET['id'];